# Django Query - How to filter object to exclude a single item?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a blog project in which i want to show other blogs link in right side apart from the blog which i am on currently? I have tried it But i am getting an error.

**Here is Code**

```
def redirect(request, slug):
try:
    exists = Blog.objects.get(title=slug)
except Blog.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404("Page Not Found")
context = {
    'content': exists,
    'otherBlogs': Blog.objects.all().exclude(exists)
}
return render(request, "blog.html", context)
```

I want to exclude `exists` from `otherBlogs` How can i do that?

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

I think you want...

```
Blog.objects.exclude(blog=exists)
```

... because `exclude()` takes a filter-style expression.

Answer (score 1):

Exclude by primary key?

```
Blog.objects.exclude(pk=exists.pk)
```